# Deploy asp.net project with mongoDB

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, deployment

Good day everyone,

I am working on a asp.net web api project that accesses a mongoDb( I am new to it). I have this sample code to access the mongoDB:

```
    private IMongoCollection<User> UserCollection { get; }

    public MongoDbService(string databaseName, string collectionName, string databaseUrl)
    {
        var mongoClient = new MongoClient(databaseUrl);
        var mongoDatabase = mongoClient.GetDatabase(databaseName);
        this.UserCollection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<User>(collectionName);
    }

    public async Task Add(User newUser) => await this.UserCollection.InsertOneAsync(newUser);

    public async Task<List<User>> GetAllUsers()
    {
        var users = new List<User>();

        var allDocuments = await this.UserCollection.FindAsync(new BsonDocument());
        await allDocuments.ForEachAsync(doc => users.Add(doc));

        return users;
    }
```

I have installed mongoDb on my machine and etc and I can connect and get what I need. My question is - how will it work when somebody pulls down the code from git? Will it create database on the fly? how will it connect to it? Will it create a local version of mongoDb database if the user has it installed? Or mongoDb must be hosted on a server for the user to connect?

Please tell if I am not clear on what I am asking. 
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*`Will it create database on the fly?`*

Yes mongodb will create the database on the fly if it does not exist

*`how will it connect to it`*

By  default if you don't pass any value to `MongoClient()` mongodb take the default which is `localhost`

*`Will it create a local version of mongoDb database if the user has it installed?`*

no Mongo will create it on the fly

*`Or mongoDb must be hosted on a server for the user to connect?`*

No Mongodb provides a standalone light version which can be installed locally 
but if your database need settings or any other data for your application you can easily import it

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So for instance if I do not pass "databaseUrl", and just specify the name of the database, it wil create a database with the name, and how would the collection work? Will it as well create default one with the name specified.